# Sending E-Mail With Error Details from ASP.Net (VB.Net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, exception

I'm guessing the answer to this question is either incredibly simple or just flat-out no, but I thought I'd take a shot at it anyway...

Is it possible to add a function to send an e-mail when an exception is caught?  For instance:

```
Try
     'Do Something
Catch ex As Exception
     SendError(ex.Message)
     Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.html")
End Try
```

In this case the SendError function is setup as a simple SMTP handler that sends off the message to a predefined e-mail account.  Obviously that's not working.  The reason I'm asking is because if the error isn't handled with a Try...Catch, then it gets logged in the Event Log.  That's great because then I know when user input is causing an issue.  With Try...Catch, I'm not able to get any error details or even know an issue exists without waiting for a user to call in.

Reading here, http://www.codemag.com/Article/0307081, shows a modification to global.asax file...but I'm wondering if that's relevant for Try...Catch, since "handling" the error also stops the Event Log writing.

Comment: It should work fine. There is nothing wrong with what you provided. Maybe the problem is with SendError.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing in the SendError method that is keepign the message from being sent, I would guess that the SendMessage method is asynchronous, returns before the mail message is sent. When ASP .NET encounters a call to Repsonse.Redirect, it will kill the current request too early  and not wait for SendMessage to do its work.

See if you can wait before calling Redirect?

Answer (score 0):

The Application_Error Method will capture unhandled exceptions (without try..catch). As you can see the example explains how to use EventLog from System.Diagnostics to log errors in the Event Log.

To log errors and send emails change your your method to

```
Sub SendError(ByVal ErrorDescription As String)

    'Create the event log record if it does not exist
    Dim EventLogName As String = "MySample"
    If (Not EventLog.SourceExists(EventLogName)) Then
        EventLog.CreateEventSource(EventLogName, EventLogName)
    End If

    'Add a record to the new event log entry
    Dim Log As New EventLog()
    Log.Source = EventLogName
    Log.WriteEntry(ErrorDescription, EventLogEntryType.Error)

    'Send an email to admin when site wide error occurs
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    Dim ErrorMessage = _
       "The error description is as follows : " _
       & ErrorDescription 
    mail.From = "jduffy@takenote.com"
    mail.To = "info@takenote.com"
    mail.Subject = "Error in the Site"
    mail.Priority = MailPriority.High
    mail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text
    mail.Body = ErrorMessage
    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "put.your.SMTP.server.here"
    SmtpMail.Send(mail)

End Sub
```

P.S.
There are few modules like [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) which you can use to log errors in xml, database or send via emails.